# Placing text inline after a Header

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
<h3> HEADER </h3>
<a href="link">Edit</a>
```

How would I place the link so it comes directly after the Header? It should appear like --

```
**HEADER** link
```

I was thinking to `float: left` the link, but it was still appearing on the line after HEADER. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By giving the header inline

```
h3 {
 display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Also can use

```
h3 {
 display: inline-block:
}
```

to keep height of header element.